# Does there exists a continuous function $f(x)$ such that $f(0)=10,f(2)=2, f'(x) \le 1,\forall x\in (0,2)?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, mean-value-theorem

Does there exists a continuous function $f(x)$ such that $f(0)=10,f(2)=2, f'(x)  \le 1,\forall x\in (0,2)?$(Hint:-Use Mean Value theorem)

**My Attempt**
Assume there exists a function satisfy Mean value theorem premises. So, there exists $c\in(0,2):$
$f(2)=f(0)=f'(c)(2-0)\leq 2$. We know that $f(2)-f(0)=2-10=-8$. which satisfies Mean value theorem. Does it imply the existence? Please help me.

Comment: $f(x) = 10-4x$ does the job. Or do you mean $|f'(x)| \le 1$?

Comment: No just $f'(x)\leq 1.$ I know for  $|f'(x)|\leq 1$ It does not exists.

Comment: Well, then such a function obviously exists, and you don't need the mean-value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

$f(2) < f(0)$, so just a straight line connecting those points would have a negative slope.

You can verify its existence with MVT, of course.

Comment: $f(2)$ is *less* than $f(0)$. And what do you mean with “very its existence with MVT”?

Comment: Right!
f`(c) = f(0) - f(2)/(0-2) = 10-2/-2 = -4 such that 0 < c < 2 exists is what MVT states. And -4 < 1.